# How do I store images into my persistent storage? Where do I encode and decode it? How do I display it using Jinja in HTML?

Tags: python, flask, base64, jinja2

I am unsure how should I used base64 to encode and decode my image, as well as where should I place the codes for encoding and decoding at. I am also unsure of how should I display it in Jinja Html.

I have already tried encoding my image but I am unsure whether I did the right way or not. I have also tried to decode it but it can seem to run my program.

## main.py

`@app.route('/camera', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])`
def camera():

```
``list = []
``with shelve.open('PerStorageCamera.db') as d:
    `enter code here`for key in d:
        `enter code here`for i in d[key]:
            `enter code here`list.append(i)

``form = FormSelect1(request.form)
``form1 = FormSelect2(request.form)
``location_data = form.location.data

``return render_template('camera.html', form=form, form1 = form1, location_data = location_data, list = list)
```

## part of my codes for my class

``class Cameras:

```
``wdlands = []

``def __init__(self, location, camera):
    ``self.__location = location
    ``self.__camera = camera
    ``self.add()

``def get_location(self):
    ``return self.__location

``def get_camera(self):
    ``return self.__camera

``def add(self):
    ``if self.__location == 'wdlands':
        ``self.__class__.wdlands.append(self)
```

## objects created to append into persistent storage

`wdlands1 = Cameras('wdlands', 'Woodlands Causeway (Towards Johor)')`
wdlands2 = Cameras('wdlands', 'Woodlands Checkpoint (Towards BKE)')

## .html

``{% for i in list %}

``{% if location_data == "wdlands" %}

`{% if i.get_location() == "wdlands" %}`

                   `<tr><th>Camera: </th><td>{{ i.get_camera() }}</td></tr>`

```
          ``<form action= "http://localhost:5000/myjourney" method= "get">
                 {{ form.submit }}
          ``</form>
          ``<br>
     ``{% endif %}`
```

I am expecting to have different images for each of my objects that is appended into the persistent storage

Comment: I am stuck at the part where I have to encode and decode my image, and then display into Jinja. However, I don't know which part of my code is required